# Align text to side of screen (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, alignment, screen, frame

Using Swiftui I'm creating a chat application. I'm trying to align the text so that it appears on the right side of the screen and then messages from the other user will appear on the left. I have tried using VStack and using leading and trailing alignment, I have also tried just aligning the text attribute. I have a text, and then two buttons. I would like the trash can button and pencil button to all evenly line up on the right side.

[image]

```
            VStack (alignment: .trailing ) {
                HStack {
                    Text(data.text)
                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                        .padding(.top, 4)
                        .padding(.leading, 8)
                        .padding(.trailing, 8)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showingPopover = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.deleteData(id: data.id)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is enough to use frame alignment for text, depending to user it can be conditionally changed in place, like

```
Text(data.text)
    .padding(.bottom, 4)
    .padding(.top, 4)
    .padding(.leading, 8)
    .padding(.trailing, 8)
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .background(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
    .cornerRadius(20)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: isMe ? .trailing : .leading) // << here !!
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `Spacer()` in the beginning of the `HStack`:

```
            VStack (alignment: .trailing ) {
                HStack {

                    // This Spacer() will "push" the text to the right
                    Spacer()

                    Text(data.text)
                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                        .padding(.top, 4)
                        .padding(.leading, 8)
                        .padding(.trailing, 8)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showingPopover = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.deleteData(id: data.id)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Similarly, for the replies put a `Spacer()` at the end of the `HStack`, too push the text to the left.

Comment: The answer from Asperi is great. I just wanted to point out padding can have `.vertical` and `.horizontal` which removes two lines as you can combine top and bottom as well as leading and trailing.